# Get numbers of all screens in Xlib

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

I've been googling for quite a long time and I just can't find any information on how to get screen_number for every screen connected to computer. [Here](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/display-macros.html) I found a list of macros and some of them (like for example ScreenOfDisplay(display, screen_number) ) use argument screen_number. However there is no such macro that could give me a list of those numbers (one for every connected screen). I know how to get number of default screen (DefaultScreen() ) and count of all screens ( ScreenCount() ) but what about other screens? I noticed that screen_number of default screen is 0, although I have only one screen connected to my computer so I can't really test what happens when there are more of them. I think that screen_number could be assigned in a very simple way which is screen_number=0 for first screen,screen_number=1 for second,screen_number=2 for third and so on but as I said... I can't test wheather it's true and even if I had multiple screens how could I be sure that it works like this for all computers .Please ,if anyone of you has more experience with X11 and knows all details about how it works,tell me if I am right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ScreenCount(dpy)` macro and `int XScreenCount(Display*)` function both return the number of screens connected to the display. Valid screen numbers are 0 to `ScreenCount(dpy)-1`. Macros in `Xlib.h` confirm:

```
#define ScreenCount(dpy)    (((_XPrivDisplay)dpy)->nscreens)
#define ScreenOfDisplay(dpy, scr)  (&((_XPrivDisplay)dpy)->screens[scr])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your source ([2.2.1. Display Macros](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/display-macros.html)) provides enough information.  Normally the default screen-number is `0`, e.g., when connecting to the local host you could use `:0.0` as indicated in the documentation for [XOpenDisplay](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html).

That is "normally".  If you run VNC, normally *that* runs on a different *display* (the first `0` in the simple connection string shown).

But (reading the documentation), when an application calls `XOpenDisplay`, *it* asks for the given screen-number (which the X server may/may not honor):

> ***screen_number***
>   
>   Specifies the screen to be used on that server. Multiple screens can be controlled by a single X server. The screen_number sets an internal variable that can be accessed by using the [DefaultScreen()](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/display-macros.html#DefaultScreen) macro or the [XDefaultScreen()](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/display-macros.html#DefaultScreen) function if you are using languages other than C (see ["Display Macros"](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/information.html#display)).